# How to search phrase in Solr?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am searching some phrase in `Solr` of `Name` field. I tryed different comfigurations for `Name`, to be of type `string` or any custom `TextField`.

```
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" 
  docValues="true" />
  <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" 
sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
     <analyzer>
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" replace="all" 
  replacement="" pattern="([^a-z])"/>
     </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

I defined `Name` like this:

then tried like string:

Also I tried different tokenizers and filters combinations without success.

**This is what I want**: I have phrase 'test split' and I have some entries that have Name `'test'`, `'test 124'`,`'testblablabla'` and `'test split 124'`.
What I find out is that `'test'` entry is first match in my example,and 'test split' has much **much lower ranking** altought it has more matching letters.
Why is that??

I am testing using solr admin interface and my q (query) parametar is:
`Name:*test split*`

**EDIT 1:**

I also tryed to create copyField called ExactName which has this configuration:

```
 <fieldType name="exact" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer> 
 </fieldType>
```

and I search like this:

```
Name:*test split* OR (ExactName:*test split*)^5.0
```

Still 'test' comes much before 'test split' :(

Comment: Have you tried using the `pf`, `pf2` or `pf3` parameters for the (e)dismax handlers? Those are created to give boosts to matching sequences. Also remember that wild card searches will skip most parts of the analysis chain.

Comment: What to write there? My field name 'Name'. I tryied but still nothing

Comment: The ranking of the documents has to do with the lucence scoring function, which was [`tf-idf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) before Solr 6 and [`BM25`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) after. [Here is a good post comparing the two.](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what do you want ?
Do you want to return only results for your phrase ? or boost more phrase matches in comparison to other types of matches ?

The edismax (and its properties) are probably your solution.
You can play with the mm parameter ( configuring the minimum match for clauses) and the pf( which boost phrases match) . [1]

If you just want the phrase to match : "test split" query should do the trick.
Don't use * wildcard queries, use a proper analysis to split the tokens, wildcard queries are very inefficient in general.

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html

[2] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thepf_PhraseFields_Parameter

Comment: +1 for "wildcard queries are very inefficient in general.". Comes only with tons of hands-on experience.

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts to solve this problem is actually correct. There are multiple ways to do this. It is possible to solve this at query-time by boosting `span queries`, but more efficient is to do this also at indexing time.

What often is done for name searching is indeed boosting phrases. You could add a filter in the `exact` fieldType. Checkout `shingles` with the [Shingle Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter) with a default of `minShingleSize` of `2`. Shingles are token n-grams.

You could create a fieldType without lowercasing as well by adding an extra `copyField` and also with the `Shingle Filter`.

Then boosting the fields is the next step. If you use the eDisMax query parser, you could use the `bf` parameter to boost the fields:

- Case-sensitive (no lower-casing) + shingles has highest boost
- Case-insensitive (with lower-casing) + shingles with 2nd highest boost
- Standard field without boost.